# Cumulative distinct count grouped by category

Tags: cumulative-sum

I am trying to get cumulative distinct count, but it should be run per category (in my example, City) and not over all the values.

My query is:

> SELECT City, MinDate, count(userId) over (order by MinDate) as [Running Total UserIds]
>
> FROM (
> SELECT UserId, min(mydate) MinDate FROM t GROUP BY UserId
> ) t

When running this query I get the following result:

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfWVS.png)

I would like to get the following:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i50Qz.png)

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the schema of the tables you are dealing with a sample of the data in them.

It's not clear where City comes from in this example. Is it a column in t?

Comment: It is possible that using a PARTITION BY argument as well as ORDER BY in your OVER clause will give you what you need.

Comment: thank you @rpcutts! Your suggestion worked for me

Comment: Glad to hear it. When you get a chance could you post your solution as an answer to your question? In case anyone visits this page with a similar problem.